# Convertir a JSON Java Script

Tags: javascript, java, json, google-datastore

Estoy trabajando en Java JSP y JavaScript, y necesito convertir el resultado de una consulta DataStore de formato:

```
<Entity [Usuario(5523854313120)]:
    Email = andres@hotmail.com
    PrimerNombre = Andres
    Rol = Administrador
   Password = andres125
>
```

al formato JSON:

```
{"Email ":"andres@hotmail.com","PrimerNombre ":"Andres","Rol ":"Administrador", "Password":"andres125"}
```

Éste es el código:

```
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Query q=new Query("Usuario");
PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);
Entity result=pq.asSingleEntity();
```

Comment: Podrias colocar el codigo que estas usando para hacer la conversión

Comment: ¿El _resultado_ en qué variable está almacenada?

Comment: Lo Guardo en result:                                                         
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
            Query q=new Query("Usuario");
            PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);
            Entity result=pq.asSingleEntity();

Answer (score 0):

Lo ideal seria convertir este objeto a un objeto java común y luego utilizar la librería java Jackson como lo señala aquí.

http://chuwiki.chuidiang.org/index.php?title=Java_y_json_con_jackson

Saludos...

Answer (score 0):

Tambien depende de la forma en que estas mostrando los datos en el jsp.

- Si estas haciendo uso de REST Api, puedes usar jackson y el se encarga de hacer el parseo de los model de java a json. Aqui tienes un ejemplo sencillo: [JSON Example with jersey jackson](https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/)
- Si estas ejecutando el codigo de java desde el jsp, entonces te recomiendo estos dos recursos usando jackson:

  - https://springframework.guru/processing-json-jackson/
  - https://www.journaldev.com/2324/jackson-json-java-parser-api-example-tutorial

Saludos!!!.